# React Hook alert prompt appears twice, how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My alert prompt showing 2 times in React

I use this syntax

```
  const [namaTamu, setNamaTamu] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePrompt = () => {
      const input = prompt('Masukkan nama:');
      if (input !== null) {
        setNamaTamu(input);
      } else {
        setNamaTamu("Tamu Undangan");
      }
    };

    handlePrompt();
  }, []);
```

Can anyone help me why my alert prompt showing 2 times? i need it just to show 1 time

Comment: This is likely due to StrictMode being on. See the answer to the other question. StrictMode intentionally double invokes the effect in development mode.